# N to N relationship, searching lines that are not related

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: Lancamento and Pagamento. These two tables have a N to N relationship, because of that I have third table: lancamentoHasPagamento.

I want to seach all the lines in table lancamento that are not related to a line the table pagamento.

I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM lancamento l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN lancamento_has_pagamento hp ON l.codigo != hp.codigo_lancamento 
WHERE bol_quitado = 0 
AND YEAR(l.data_vencimento) = 2015
AND MONTH(l.data_vencimento) = 10
AND l.valor BETWEEN 475.00 AND 525.00;
```

However this code repeats the searching in each line of the table lancamento_has_pagamento, do you guys have any solution for this?

Example:

lancamento_has_pagamento

[image]

Let's say I have line in the Lacamento table that has data = 2015-10-15 and valor = 500.00 adn the line cod is 128. I'm expecting the code to return just line 128 just one time.

Comment: could you illustrate your case with some raw data source and expected result set please?

Comment: I just added what you asked. Wainting your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join condition should be "=" not "!=", and then you should test that the foreign key to your other table is NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM lancamento l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN lancamento_has_pagamento hp ON l.codigo = hp.codigo_lancamento 
WHERE hp.codigo_lancamento IS NULL
//... your other conditions come here.
;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM lancamento l 
LEFT JOIN lancamento_has_pagamento hp 
ON l.codigo = hp.codigo_lancamento
WHERE bol_quitado = 0 
AND YEAR(l.data_vencimento) = 2015
AND MONTH(l.data_vencimento) = 10
AND l.valor BETWEEN 475.00 AND 525.00
GROUP BY l.codigo # <-- this codigo column is your key column
HAVING COUNT(hp.codigo_lancamento)=0;
```

or even simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM lancamento l 
LEFT JOIN lancamento_has_pagamento hp 
ON l.codigo = hp.codigo_lancamento
WHERE hp.codigo_lancamento IS NULL
AND bol_quitado = 0 
AND YEAR(l.data_vencimento) = 2015
AND MONTH(l.data_vencimento) = 10
AND l.valor BETWEEN 475.00 AND 525.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!